# Updating string property based on textfield entry

Tags: javafx-8

I have a frame, with a text field, the layout is naff but thats not the aim at the moment.

I want to update a string property based on whatever is entered into the textfield, and then have it also print out in the console below (eclipse)

Similar to updating within the code itself by calling .set()

here is my code -

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class TextEntry extends Application
{
    private static StringProperty text = 
            new SimpleStringProperty("text");

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        TextField enterText = new TextField();
        enterText.setFont(Font.font("SanSerif",20));

        enterText.setOnMousePressed(e ->{
            text.bind(enterText.textProperty());
            System.out.println("the new value is: " + text);
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(enterText);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Text Entry");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple things including the line in the code above -

```
text.set("").bind(enterText.textProperty());
```

and

```
text.textProperty().bind(enterText.textProperty());
```

the second of which is syntactically incorrect i realise, but I can't think of a solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to bind the properties once, not every time a key is pressed. Then just add a `ChangeListener` to the property:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new Pane();

    TextField enterText = new TextField();
    enterText.setFont(Font.font("SanSerif",20));

    text.bind(enterText.textProperty());

    text.addListener((obs, oldTextValue, newTextValue) -> 
        System.out.println("The new value is "+newTextValue));

    root.getChildren().addAll(enterText);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Text Entry");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Of course, with the code above the extra property is redundant: you can just do

```
enterText.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldTextValue, newTextValue) -> 
    System.out.println("The new value is "+newTextValue));
```

but maybe there are other reasons you need the additional property.

Comment: Thats brill, thanks! that was starting to bug me a little bit!